# QGIS: How to convert date values with format d-m-yyyy in a string field, into date values with format yyyy-mm-dd in a date field?

Tags: convert, qgis-3, date

I have date values with the format d-m-yyyy in QGIS.
They are in string field.
I want to convert them into date values with the format yyyy-mm-dd.
I want them in a date field.

Can this be done without doing something in Python?

Comment: Which software are you using or want to use?

Comment: Sorry, QGIS 3.0

Comment: Can you give examples on how your data looks if your format is _d-m-yyyy_ please? Do you have dates like `1-2-2013` instead of `01-02-2013`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! The answer of @Kazuhito down here works perfect btw!

Comment: @Rob - Great! Don't forget to accept his answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use the `Field calculator`.

Expression would be:

```
to_date(
  concat(regexp_substr("old_date", '([^-]+$)'), 
         '-', 
         lpad(regexp_substr("old_date", '[-](\\d*)[-]'), 2, 0), 
         '-', 
         lpad(regexp_replace("old_date", '([-].*$)', ''), 2, 0)
   )
 )
```

Please replace `"old_date"` by your actual string field.